# How To fast render data using katex in react native?

Tags: katex

Question :- **How To fast render data using katex in react native?**

Description :- I am using **Katex**, When app is run then katex data is shown after **2-3 seconds**. How it is fast like app is run then data is visible not time delay.

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to implement katex but getting errors! How do you implement it?

Comment: What is error? Post your error screenshot.